# Why does MainAxisAlignment of a Column have different outputs in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I used `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,` in my "Column" to place some content on the bottom of the screen. This works fine.
I needed to add a picture, this picture was also shown at the bottom of the screen, align and positioned didn't change it. So I put the Column as a child in another column, this allows me, to put the picture in a row, and place it in the right top corner. But now the content of the original column is centered in the screen. What should I do?

Should look like this:

[image: layout]

Here my code:

```
Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      image: DecorationImage(
        image: AssetImage('assets/Images/backgroundhomescreen.png'),
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
    ),
    child:Column(
      children: [
        Row(                                                    //Logo
            children: [
              Image(
                image: AssetImage('assets/Images/logo.png'),
                width: 120,
              ),
            ]
        ),
        Column(
          //crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          // mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: <Widget>[...
```

Comment: could you draw of a screen you want to achieve?

Comment: @Ruslanbek0809 I added a picture of the layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either set the crossAxisAlignment to `CrossAxisAlignment.end` to align all the children to the right or wrap the `TopBox` widget in `Align`.

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container( //Outer Container
      height: 900,
      width: 400,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
      ),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
        children: [
//           Align(
//           alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
//           child:  TopBox()
//             ,),
          TopBox(),
          Spacer(),
          BottomBox(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BottomBox extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.blue,
      height: 200,
    );
  }
}

class TopBox extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(15),
      color: Colors.blue,
      height: 100,
      width: 175,
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could simply achieve custom spacing in flutter using the [spacer widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Spacer-class.html)